# Simulate VMS FTP on Windows

Tags: windows, ftp, version, vms

All,

Just wondering if it was possible to simulate the VMS functionality of FTP in Windows?

VMS supports/ed versioning of files that are uploaded to a server using FTP.  For example, if you upload a file mytextfile.txt three times, you would end up with mytextfile.txt, mytextfile.txt;1 and mytextfile.txt;2.  The ;version is appended for each file of the same name you upload.

We need to do something similar for our test environment.

However I cannot see anyway to do this with Windows FTP.  We are running Windows 2003 Server with FileZilla FTP Server on.  I have not yet come across anyway to do this, if it can be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Andez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fake it manually:

```
put localfilename remotefilename
put localfilename remotefilename;1
put localfilename remotefilename;3
```

but you'd have to keep track of how many copies/versions of that remotefilename exist and build the new filename yourself. in VMS, this is done automatically at the filesystem level - FTP has nothing do with the auto-versioning.

Comment: Cheers Marc.  Was hoping there would be something available.